# Is there a time limit for airline's responses to compensation requests?

Tags: air-travel

I have been on a KLM flight from Prague to Amsterdam, with a connection to Portland. Due to refueling issues on KLM's side in Amsterdam, my plane from Prague to Amsterdam got delayed by 2 hours, causing me to miss my connection, and forcing me to stay overnight in Amsterdam.

According to [my rights as a EU citizen](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm), I am entitled to a compensation of *600 Euros* (the desk lady confirmed this to me).

I filled out a respective complaint form, and started waiting. After two weeks, I contacted KLM about the processing of my request, leading to one of those standard "we apologize for incoveniences ... are working at our best ... will get back to you as quickly as possible ..." messages.

It has been one month now, and my request hasn't been processed yet.

Do I have the right to a timely processing of my request / an information about the remaining time it'll take?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant regulation, [261/2004 Art 7](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/resource.html?uri=cellar:439cd3a7-fd3c-4da7-8bf4-b0f60600c1d6.0004.02/DOC_1&format=PDF), affirms that right, and says nothing about timeliness. Reimbursements are due within 7 days (Art 8(1), 10(2))

Comment: > Reimbursements are due within 7 days (Art 8(1), 10(2))

This seems to apply only for complete reimbursements, that is, when I have chosen to cancel my flight and return home. I'm referring to the partial reimbursement (Art 7).

Comment: Is there no other, more general EU law, applying in such cases?

Comment: The regulation refers to article 7 money as "compensation", not "reimbursement" (which applies to a situation where a customer does not receive what they paid for, e.g. cancellation or downgrading). That is it, as far as EU law goes.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant, sorry for the misleading term in my question. Will update it.